# BizTalk oracle error when configure bindings

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I configured BizTalk 2020 Server with CU1 and I installed Oracle Client in this way.

- Download ODAC183_x64 & ODAC183Xcopy_32bit.
- I install odac183 with setup and then I'm going to put in gac oracle.dataaccess ( Version=4.122.18.3) in x64 and x86 version.
- I imported and old binding and oracle connection seems ok.

But, when I'm going to change configuration, I receive this error[image: Invalid binding. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Common). The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. (Oracle.DataAccess). An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007008) (Oracle.DatacAccess)]
Any suggestion?

Comment: Note: CU2 for BizTalk 2020 came out a bit over a week ago.  Not that it looks to have any fixes for the Oracle Adapter.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003151-cumulative-update-2-for-microsoft-biztalk-server-2020-324a3d5d-8d87-49aa-b7e4-1f0733acbb09

Comment: What happens if you try and create a new port with the Oracle adapter, do you get the same error?

Comment: i get the same error, also creation of a new port.
I solved, but im not very satisfied,  installing the oracle client version 12c instead of the 18c, and after adding in the machine config:

  <assemblyBinding xmlns = "urn: schemas-microsoft-com: asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name = "Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken = "89b483f429c47342" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion = "4.122.18.3" newVersion = "4.122.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>

Thanks

Comment: Update: 

Problem was that I installed Oracle.DataAcces(x64-x86) through gacutil.

You should install dll with:  

 oraprovcfg.exe /action:gac /providerpath:Oracle.DataAccess.dll

that supplies to put dll in gac and change machine.config.



Ps. from version 18c , Oracle Client don't install automatically dll in gac and don't update machine.config .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I installed Oracle.DataAcces(x64-x86) through gacutil.
You should install dll with:
oraprovcfg.exe /action:gac /providerpath:Oracle.DataAccess.dll that supplies to put dll in gac and change machine.config.

> From version 18c , Oracle Client don't install automatically dll in
> gac and don't update
>
> machine.config

Comment: The cause of the problem is that "incorrect format" means the BizTalk Server Administration Console runs in 32 bit, and requires 32-bit ODAC to be installed.