# How does BizTalk (2020) know which version of Oracle.DataAccess to use?

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I was originally trying to use Oracle 19c, but it wasn't working with our User-Defined-Types DLls, so I decided to make it the same as our BT2016 system, using 12.1.

So originally, the old Windows 2.0 GAC has 2.122.19.1 installed.  I removed it, and now it contains only 2.121.1.0 as shown below.

[image]

Yet when I run a BizTalk test, BizTalk is looking for 4.122.18.3.  I had reported a similar issue earlier: [BizTalk 2020 - The system cannot find the file Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76018409/biztalk-2020-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-oracle-dataaccess-version-4-122), and got around it using a redirect.  I think you can only redirect to newer versions, probably not to older versions, but I'm not sure.

**Error:**

```
A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port "TestProject.EBSSendReceivePort_WCF-Oracle" with URI "oracledb://ABCDEV1/" is suspended. 
 Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
```

Do I have to use 18.3?  According to a PDF by Sandro Pereira available on the BizTalk360 website, the following are supported.  So how does BizTalk know which one to load, if you switched between them like I did?

[image]

So, is there a registry setting, a config setting that tells BizTalk to load 18.3, or does it load that, and we have to redirect to newer and/or older versions.

Comment: Check the machine.config, I think it's in there.